# Sorting a List of 3d coplanar points to be clockwise or counterclockwise

Tags: math, geometry, linear-algebra

I have a list of 3D points. I know they are all coplanar. I have the center that I want to sort them around and the normal to the plane on which the points and the center lie. How can I test if one point is right (or left) of another point?

I understand how to do it in 2D. [Sort points in clockwise order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989100/sort-points-in-clockwise-order) explains how to compare 2d points. So I think I need to somehow covert all the points and the center to local 2d plane coordinates. How can I do that? Is it the most efficient way to solve this problem?

```
//from link:
// a and b are points
//center is the center around which to determine order
//int num = (a.x-center.x) * (b.y-center.y) - (b.x - center.x) * (a.y - center.y);
//if num=0 then they're on the same line
//if num <0 or num>0 then a is to the left or right of b
```

How would I adapt this to handle 3d coplanar points?

Comment: "Clockwise" has no meaning in 3-d, since it depends on which way you look at the plane. Flip the plane around, and suddenly clockwise is counter-clockwise.

Comment: @woodchips The problem is not unique to 3-d. Not all 2-d coordinate systems are defined the same way either. In both cases, you just need to define what is meant by "clockwise".

Comment: I see what you are saying, that it a good thing to know. Do you think that specifying the plane's normal direction would clear this up? Clockwise doesn't mean a whole lot to me right now either, but I still need to order the points in some consistent direction.

Comment: Yes, if you specify the normal direction, then this will give you a consistent definition of clockwise.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's no need to convert everything to 2D.

You have the center **C** and the normal **n**. To determine whether point **B** is clockwise or counterclockwise from point **A**, calculate dot(**n**, cross(**A**-**C**, **B**-**C**)). If the result is positive, **B** is counterclockwise from **A**; if it's negative, **B** is clockwise from **A**.

Comment: How would I get the angle between A and B? I added this but it seems too complicated:
`sign(dot(n, cross(A-C, B-C)) * cos^{-1} { dot(A-C, B-C) / (|| A-C||_2 * ||B-C||_2) }`

Comment: @stephanmg: Yes, that seems overcomplicated. I'd probably define two new vectors `CA=A-C; CB=B-C;`, normalise `CA/=||CA||; CB/=||CB||;` and then use [`atan2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Comment: Thanks. I thought I'd want to use atan2, however people have concerns usign atan2. Why? I couldn't quickly find one convincing argument.

Comment: This approach will fail if A and B are co-linear.

Comment: @stephanmg: Do you mean A and B are colinear with C? (Obviously A and B are always colinear.) If so, then the result is zero, which I would argue is the correct answer; in that case B is neither clockwise nor counterclockwise from A. (Or both, if you like.)

Comment: Beta: Well, in this case you are right. I had a slightly different underlying problem, where this would be not the behaviour I want. But this depends on the problem. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: My point is actually that I'm getting the same value from dot(. , .) if I use for instance these points: B = [ -7.04462  -21.606552 -14.272003 ] and 
B' = [ -5.13538  -21.606552 -14.272003 ] A = [ -6.09     -19.84723  -14.785682 ] and the center C = [ -6.09, -21.0437, -14.4402 ]. Then dot(.  , .) will give me the same value for B and B'. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @stephanmg: What are you using for n?

Comment: For n I calculate the cross product by cross(A-C, B-C).

Comment: Should I actually be calculating n = cross(A, B) and normalize n by n / ||n||? This yields the correct/expected behaviour.

Comment: @stephanmg: n is the normal. You can't just combine different vectors with different operations at random until you get the result you expected; You have go back and understand the mathematics before you write code, or you'll keep having these problems.

Comment: Beta: Thanks for the suggestion, it seems working through the maths again helped spot the problem.

Comment: If you came here to sort a polygon CCW or CW then one can proceed with the check @Beta mentioned. Make sure you iteratively repeat this and make sure to always pick the positive or negative value.