# Select Hexagonal Face in OctahedronGeometry THREE.js

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, three.js, geometry

I have a geodesic sphere - which was created using `THREE.OctahedronGeometry` -  I would like to group triangular faces into hexagonal faces, so they can be selected. I'm at a loss about how to approach this problem or if it's even feasible. Any insight would be appreciated.

Here's an example:
[image]

```
createGeodesicSphere =->
        geometry = new THREE.OctahedronGeometry(200, 3)
        material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color        : 0xFFFFFF,
            shading      : THREE.FlatShading,
            side         : THREE.DoubleSide,
            vertexColors : THREE.FaceColors,
            overdraw     : true 
            })

        # Explode geometry so each face has unique vertices
        explodeModifier = new THREE.ExplodeModifier()
        explodeModifier.modify(geometry)

        geodesicMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry , material)
        geodesicFaces = geometry.faces  

        for i in [0..geodesicFaces.length-1]
            geodesicFaces[i].color.setRGB(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random())

        geodesicMesh.position.x = 0
        geodesicMesh.position.y = 0
        geodesicMesh.position.z = 0

        scene.add(geodesicMesh)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely its not possible but you can try a voronoi diagram which is very close to a hexagon:[Spherical Voronoi Tessellation with Java 7: need fix for winding vertices around faces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011166/spherical-voronoi-tessellation-with-java-7-need-fix-for-winding-vertices-around).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'm going to look into this - I'll mark your answer correct if it pans out.

Comment: @ForeignObject: I think a hexagon tiling would be not equal.

Comment: I agree, I'm pretty sure it's not possible to cover a sphere in hexagons of equal size.

Comment: @ForeignObject:If my answer is helpful please consider to accept it and/or upvote it! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, after doing more research your answer helped to point me in a better direction.