# C# LINQ sort lambda implement (sort 3d points in counterclockwise)

Tags: c#, linq

I've got the good compare idea from this link.
[Sorting a List of 3d coplanar points to be clockwise or counterclockwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370636/sorting-a-list-of-3d-coplanar-points-to-be-clockwise-or-counterclockwise)
However, I tried to implement it, but seems not working.
Did I miss anything?

```
private int sortCounterClockWise(Vector3 center, Vector3 normal, Vector3 pointA, Vector3 pointB)
{
    return (int)(Vector3.Dot(normal, Vector3.Cross(pointA - center, pointB - center)));
}

points.Sort((a, b) => sortCounterClockWise(center, normal, a, b));
```

Comment: What do you mean `but seems not working.` by that? What is not working?

Comment: The code snippet ignores thee return value of `IEnumerable.Sort()`