# sorting a vector not obeying sort function

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, geometry

I'm trying to sort a vector of points in clockwise order around 0,0 based on [Sort points in clockwise order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989100/sort-points-in-clockwise-order) .

The logic of the sort function makes sense and checks out when I manually calculate the results for individual points. However, the resulting vector does not appear to be sorted according to the sort function. For instance, here are the first 4 elements after one particular run of the sort:

```
[22.3701,450.519,-1045]   <- correct
[-22.429,-29.0513,-1006]  <- should be in position 2
[-147.806,65.0482,-1095]  <- should be in position 3
[68.0652,590.091,-942]    <- should be in position 1
```

This case should be caught by the first guard clause of the sort algorithm:

```
if ( a.x >= 0 && b.x < 0 ) return true
```

becomes:

```
if ( 68.0652 >= 0 && -22.429 < 0 ) return true
```

which should certainly sort the (68.0652,590.091) point higher.

Here's my implementation of the sort function, simplified because my center point is (0,0):

```
bool sortVectorsClockwise( const Vec3f &a, const Vec3f &b )
{
    if ( a.x >= 0 && b.x < 0 ) return true;
    if ( a.x == 0 && b.x == 0 ) return a.y > b.y;

    float det = a.x * b.y - b.x * a.y;
    if ( det < 0 ) return true;
    if ( det > 0 ) return false;

    // points a and b are on the same line from the center, check which is
    // closer to the center
    return a.xy().length() > b.xy().length();
}
```

and I call and print the results like this:

```
sort( points.begin(), points.end(), sortVectorsClockwise );

for ( auto &p : points ) {
    cout << p << endl;
}
```

I'm compiling using XCode 4.6, LLVM 4.2, C++11.

Comment: Almost certainly your sort function doesn't define a *strict weak ordering*.

Comment: I'd take a look at the atan2() function and only resort to the length if the angle doesn't provide a difference. I'd still want to know why the code fails to provide the expected results. What keeps you from outputting the result of every comparison, you seem to have a test case already?

Comment: thanks, yeah, reimplemented by finding the angle to the y-axis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I suspected (actually worse than I suspected). I tried this code

```
int main()
{
    Vec3f a(22.3701, 450.519, -1045);
    Vec3f b(-22.429,-29.0513,-1006);
    if (sortVectorsClockwise(a, b))
        cout << "a<b\n";
    if (sortVectorsClockwise(b, a))
        cout << "b<a\n";
}
```

The output is

```
a<b
b<a
```

In other words your sort function is saying that one value is less than another **and vice versa**. Obviously no sorting algorithm can handle that.

Comment: yeah, just realized every time I manually verified it, I was assuming that every point would be passed in in the `a` position :P Obviously, that would make for a crazy-slow sort function.