# Get 2d alpha shape boundary vertices from set of points

Tags: c++, cgal

I haven't used CGAL before, and all I want is a function that takes a 2d set of points and alpha parameter, and returns a vector of points that represents the bounding polygon. I can make an alpha shape object, but I don't know how to get a vector from there.
EDIT: One caveat is that there may be several disconnected components, and I would want to know that somehow. Is there a neat solution such that I get an ordered vector of vertices for each polygon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going over the edges instead and used that to find the vertices in order.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem and finally ended up sorting all vertices like suggested in the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989100/sort-points-in-clockwise-order). Maybe, it would help someone.

I'm not exactly satisfied by this approach, though. @Flowers, do you still have code with which you iterated over edges? I couldn't manage to do this. Sorry, I have not enough reputation to ask it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Alpha_shape_2 A(points.begin(), points.end(),
                FT(10000),
                Alpha_shape_2::GENERAL);

std::vector<Alpha_shape_2::Point> points;

for (Alpha_shape_2::Alpha_shape_vertices_iterator
       avit = A.alpha_shape_vertices_begin(),
       avit_end=A.alpha_shape_vertices_end();
       avit!=avit_end; ++avit)
{
  points.push_back(avit->point());
}
```

See the reference manual of the function [here](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Alpha_shapes_2/classCGAL_1_1Alpha__shape__2.html#a66e0477bd1ebd44bec1e50b8a7ebc4ef).

Comment: Thanks, but that's pretty much what I have right now, but the vertices don't seem to come in order.

Comment: What order are you looking for?

Comment: For each polygon, I would like to get the vertices in cw or ccw order