# How am I incorrectly implementing this algorithms to sort a list of points in a spiral?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, spiral

I'm trying to sort a list of points in a consistent spiral.

The algorithms here are simply beyond me; see [this jsbin](https://jsbin.com/heduwi/edit) for an example of what I'm doing.

The graph you'll see should be as close to a spiral as possible, and currently isn't, even as I'm following the algorithm outlined [on this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989100/sort-points-in-clockwise-order) as well as a dumb "distance to center" sort.

In the jsbin there's a points-only visualization of my current failures; if you uncomment the call to `drawPoints`, and switching between "sortByStackOverflow" and "sortByCenterDistance" should let you see both of my attempts at solving.

What am I doing wrong? Where should I look for this?

The main reason I'm doing this in JS is for ease of visualization, there's no real requirement for you to help me in JS if that's not your preferred language.

Comment: Can you specify where is the list of points? I couldn't find it.

Comment: the points = generatePoints() part generates a list of x,y points and puts them in the points var. generatePoints is by the bottom of the example, it's a simple random taking the center of the window as centroid

Answer (score 0):

The two attempts you made were ordering points by distance to the center and by angular position, but they both won't build a spiral.

This is an algorithm in pseudocode that should produce something more spiraly:

```
point = farthest_from_center(points)
result = [point]
points.remove(point)
//choose a previous point so that previous_point->point is perpendicular to point->center
previous = {x: point.x-point.y+center.y , y: point.x+point.y-center.x}
while(points is not empty){
  next=least_angled_point(previous,point,points) //see below for details
  result.push(next)
  points.remove(next)
  previous=point
  point=next
}
return result
```

We want to choose at each iteration the point with the least deviation from the direction we are currently going. When starting from the point furthest from the center and with a perpendicular direction, this should produce a spiral.

Choosing the least_angled_point can be done by calculating the dot product between vectors previous->point and point->next for all possible next point in points, and choosing the highest value (dot product gives the cosine of the angle between the vectors, higher cosines correspond to lower angles).
This dot product can be calculated by:

```
function dot_product(previous,point,next){
  return (point.x-previous.x)*(next.x-point.x)+(point.y-previous.y)*(next.y-point.y)
```

This algorithm will have a complexity of n^2 in the number of points since it needs to compute the dot product from each point to all remaining points to connect, but if you don't need to make in work on thousands of points it should be fine.

I have not implemented and tested it, so if you do and find any bugs let me know and I'll try to help!

Answer (score 0):

I played around with some code and the other post you linked. This is not a full answer, but one thing I think you are missing is:

> First compute the center point

In `sortByStackoverflow` you do:

```
var center  = {x: window.innerWidth/2, y:window.innerHeight/2};
```

I would recommend changing this to the center point of all the points (that is, a non-static one). One option could be a weighted average (all points have the same weight) to calculate the 'center of mass' of all the points.

```
function sortByStackoverflow(points){
    …
    var center  = {x: 0, y:0};
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      center.x += points[i].x;
      center.y += points[i].y;
    }
    center.x /= points.length;
    center.y /= points.length;
    …
}
```

Comment: That didn't work; although I did find a succint and probably dumb way of sorting them clockwise (https://jsbin.com/yimikop/1/edit?html,css,js,output) I haven't found a way to factor the distance to this centroid too

Comment: @CarlosVergara Yes, the answer was not intended to fully solve your issue (hence the disclaimer in the beginning), but rather highlight a possible improvement.