# How to sort List<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort a Custom Class List<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163922/sort-a-custom-class-list)

I have a Generic Collector `List` and some code adding `CmsCategory` in an unordered way to the Collector. `CmsCategory` has fields `int CategoryId` and `string Title`.

```
List<CmsCategory> categories = new List<CmsCategory>();
categories.Sort();
```

After the insertion is completed I need to to get all objects in the collector sorted by `CategoryId (ascending)`.

I receive this error:

> At least one object must implement IComparable.

My questions:

- What I'm doing wrong here using `List<T`>?
- Do you know more appropriate Generic Collector for this kind of operations?

Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: This link may help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`OrderBy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) method to sort based on a property:

```
var sortedItems = categories.OrderBy(x => x.CategoryId);
```

If you need the items in a list, you can call `.ToList()`:

```
var sortedList = sortedItems.ToList();
```

The cool thing about using `OrderBy()` is that you can also use `ThenBy()` with it to sort based on a second (or third, or fourth...) property as well:

```
var reallySortedItems = categories.OrderBy(x => x.CategoryId).ThenBy(x => x.OtherProp);
```

Comment: Good approach, solved the problem. many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your custom type needs to implement the IComparable interface.

```
class CmsCategory: IComparable<CategoryID>
{
     public int CategoryID { get; set; }

     #region IComparable<CmsCategory> Members

     public int CompareTo( CmsCategory other )
     {
         if ( this.CategoryID < other.CategoryID ) return 1;
         else if ( this.CategoryID > other.CategoryID ) return -1;
         else return 0;
     }

     #endregion
}
```

Alternatively, if you need to sort on different Properties of your object in different situations, you can create appropriate implementations of IComparer and pass these into the sort method.

```
class CmsCategory_SortByName : IComparer<CmsCategory>
{
    #region IComparer<CmsCategory> Members

    public int Compare( CmsCategory x, CmsCategory y )
    {
        return string.Compare( x.Name, y.Name );
    }

    #endregion
}

var customSort = new CmsCategory_SortByName();
categories.Sort(customSort);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Linq like this:

```cs
List<CmsCategory> categories = new List<CmsCategory>();
categories = categories.OrderBy(c => c.CategoryId).ToList();
```

For more complicated scenarios you could use a Comparison:

```cs
internal class CmsCategoryComparison
{
   public static int Compare(CmsCategory a, CmsCategory b)
   {
      // return either -1, 0, 1 like the CompareTo() method would
   }
}
List<CmsCategory> categories = new List<CmsCategory>();
categories.Sort(CmsCategoryComparison.Compare);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
categories.OrderBy(x=>x.CategoryId);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 simple way to do this.

### Using delegates

```
class Book
{
    public Book(string id, string name, string author)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
        Author = author;
    }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }

}

List<Book> listBook = new List<Book>();
        listBook.Add(new Book( "103", "Code Complete", "Steve MC"  ));
        listBook.Add(new Book("101", "Effective C++", "Scott Meyers"));
        listBook.Add(new Book("102", "CLR Via C#", "Jeff Prosise"));

        listBook.Sort(
            delegate(Book a, Book b) 
            {
                return a.ID.CompareTo(b.ID);
            });
```

### Using Comparator

```
    static int CompareBook(Book a, Book b)
    {
        return a.ID.CompareTo(b.ID);
    }

        listBook.Sort( CompareBook );
```

### Using IComparable

```
class Book : IComparable
{
    public Book(string id, string name, string author)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
        Author = author;
    }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return ID.CompareTo(((Book)obj).ID);
    }

}
```

Finally it's your choice! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can either have CmsCategory inherit IComparable, or use another overload of [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) that accepts a Compare(T) delegate.

The last case could look like this:

```
categories.Sort( (x,y) => { 
 if(x.CategoryId > y.CategoryId)
  return 1;
 else if(x.CategoryId == y.CategoryId)
  return 0;
 else
  return -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `IComparable<T>` in your `CmsCategory`:

```
class CmsCategory : IComparable<CmsCategory>
{
    public int CompareTo(CmsCategory other)
    {
        return this.CategoryId.CompareTo(other.CategoryId);
    }
}
```

then you will be able to perform in-place sort:

```
List<CmsCategory> list = new List<CmsCategory> { new CmsCategory(), new CmsCategory() };
list.Sort();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the comparing function

CmsCategory.compareTo(CmsCategory)

that is able to provide a total ordering on your CmsCategory elements.

Answer (score 0):

Just do what compiler suggests: implement that interface into your CsmCategory class, if you want to sort using that Sort method.