# Order a List<T> by inner field of object

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable

Consider the code below

```
class Pin
{
   string Name; //can be either Numerical or AlphaNum
}

enum Place
{
    Left,
    Right
}

class Map
{
   Pin pin;
   Place Place;
   Rectangle Rect;
}
```

The `Pin`'s `Name` field can be only numerical or alphanumerical, so I went by string to support both.

Now My quesion is if I have a `List<Map>` how can I sort this list by Pin's Name field? I tried the code below but it can't compile:

```
map.Sort((x, y) => x.Pin.Name.CompareTo(y.Pin.Name)); 
//Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DataModels.PinMap>
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163922/sort-a-custom-class-list

Comment: What you have actually looks fine...? Are you sure your real code isn't `map = map.Sort(...);` ?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to set map equal to the result of the call to Sort. Skip that (as sort will rearrange the elements in the list you're sorting) or use map = map.OrderBy(x => x.pin.Name).ToList();

Comment: @MarcGravell It seems taht I was doing a wrong assignement I mean returning the sort result in a method. But my question on sorting still is valid.

Comment: @Sean87 then sort it, then return-it; the `List<T>.Sort` method is an in-place operation, so has no return value. i.e. `list.Sort(...); return list;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code you showed doesn't produce that compiler error. I assume that you are trying to assign the result to a new variable or to itself. Something like this:

```
map = map.Sort(...);
```

That's not possible or necessary as `List<T>.Sort` is doing an *in-place* sort, i.e. it changes the original list and therefore doesn't return anything. So, simply removing the assignment should make the compiler error go away.

If you don't want an in-place sort, simply use `Enumerable.OrderBy` in combination with `ToList` to produce a new list:

```
var result = map.OrderBy(x => x.pin.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Sounds to me like the OP just needs to replace `map = map.Sort(...);` with `map.Sort(...);`... I'm just saying that "remove the `map = `" is probably more important to highlight than the LINQ alternative

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yes. That's what I just now thought, too. I was already changing my answer as you commented. Please check.

Comment: I'd say it's good to have both, while it follows that `map = map.OrderBy(...).ToList()` has the same effect as `Sort()`, `Sort()` is faster. Conversely, `OrderBy(...)` beats `OrderBy(...).ToList()` but isn't always what one needs. Knowing about all three approaches is definitely a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to the rescue:

```
var ordered = map.OrderBy(x => x.pin.Name);
```

Assuming, of course, that none of the pins in the map is `null`. If it can be null, then:

```
var ordered = map.Where(x => x.pin != null).OrderBy(x => x.pin.Name);
```

Comment: I disagree; this does not do what the question asks: it does not sort the list.

Comment: @MarcGravell in fairness, since it looks like the problem was with assigning the result of the sort, and since we don't see whether the assignment was back to the same list or not, it's not clear that this isn't precisely what they really want.

Comment: @Jon hmmmm... perhaps; indeed, the question could be clearer on this point.

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq.

```
map = (from a in allAgents
      orderby a.AgentId
      select a).ToList<Map>();
```