# How to sort a List?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, list

I have tried to sort the list in many ways, but none work for me. I must be doing something wrong. I want to sort the List `details` then serialize it and send it to the UI, so that i have a sorted List in the UI.
So basically i want `Return strJson` to return the sorted(sorted by the sort property) List. Hope i am making sense.

```
<WebMethod(Description:="Get Home Page Items Page Wise", EnableSession:=True)> _
    <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
    Public Function GetHomePageItemsPageWise(ByVal pageIndex As String) As Object
        Dim details As New List(Of HomePageObject)()

        Dim idObject As New List(Of GetIdBasedOnInterest)()
        idObject = CType(BLL.GetDataByInterests(CType(BLL.GetAccIdFromSocialAuthSession(), Integer)), List(Of GetIdBasedOnInterest))


        Dim cmd As DbCommand = _db.GetStoredProcCommand("GetHomePageObjectPageWise")
        _db.AddInParameter(cmd, "PageIndex", SqlDbType.VarChar, pageIndex)
        _db.AddInParameter(cmd, "PageSize", SqlDbType.Int, 10)
        _db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "PageCount", SqlDbType.Int, 1)
        _db.AddInParameter(cmd, "whereStoryID", SqlDbType.VarChar, idObject(0).StoryIds)
        _db.AddInParameter(cmd, "whereAlbumID", SqlDbType.VarChar, idObject(0).AlbumIds)
        _db.AddInParameter(cmd, "wherePictureID", SqlDbType.VarChar, idObject(0).PictureIds)

        Try
            Using ds As DataSet = _db.ExecuteDataSet(cmd)
                For Each rs As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                    Dim homePageObject As New HomePageObject()

                    homePageObject.AlbumId = rs("AlbumId").ToString()
                    homePageObject.StoryTitle = rs("StoryTitle").ToString()
                    homePageObject.AlbumName = rs("AlbumName").ToString()
                    homePageObject.AlbumCover = rs("AlbumCover").ToString()
                    homePageObject.Votes = rs("Votes").ToString()
                    homePageObject.PictureId = rs("PictureId").ToString()
                    homePageObject.TableName = rs("tableName").ToString()
                    homePageObject.PageCount = CType(cmd.Parameters("@PageCount").Value, Integer)
                    homePageObject.Sort = Guid.NewGuid()
                    details.Add(homePageObject)
                    Next
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim strJson As String = js.Serialize(details.ToArray)
        Return strJson
    End Function
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort a Custom Class List<>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163922/sort-a-custom-class-list)

Comment: The sort property is a GUID and its seems useless here.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan Kindly explain, why do you say its useless? I am new to programming.

Comment: actually the guid is like a system generated string so there is no use to order the record accordingly cause its random.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan Actually my need is to randomize.

Comment: @user1593175, than try any random number instead of guid.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan Why do you suggest Random() over GUID?

Comment: Is this better? `Dim rndNum As New Random() homePageObject.Sort = rndNum.Next(100)` Kindly reply.

Comment: Using a MsgBox in a WebService method is a bad idea.  The client will never see it.

Comment: It looks like you're paging through the data, in which case you would need an `ORDER BY` in the SQL query, and I can't see where you modify the query to do that.

Comment: @AndrewMorton If the data is randomized before paging is applied, doing paging at all makes no sense.

Comment: @Magnus I agree in essence, although it looks like the randomisation happens after fetching a page of data. Maybe assigning a random value to the .Sort property is not what the OP intends, or the Pagexxx parameters are left over from some earlier version of the code as the xxxID paramemeters appear to be quite specific.

Comment: @SteveWellens Thats just for debugging.i'll remove it in production version.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I fetch the data first and then i randomize it.

Comment: @DavidStratton The question you linked helped me learn a new thing, +1 for that and this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To randomize the list you can do the following. (And you do not need the `Sort` property in `HomePageObject` to accomplish this)

```
Dim rnd As new Random()
Dim strJson As String = js.Serialize(details.OrderBy(Function(x) rnd.Next()).ToArray())
```