# Sorting a List of points C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting, point, grasshopper

I'm trying to sort a List (this Point3D is a Rhino library class). I want to have the points with the smallest X before, but I need to sort this points by the smallest Y if they have the same X. For example I have:

```
Point 1: X = 2; Y = 1
Point 2: X = 4; Y = 2
Point 3: X = 4; Y = 1
Point 4: X = 3; Y = 8
Point 5: X = 2; Y = 6
Point 6: X = 2; Y = 4
```

The order that I want to have is that:

```
Point 1: X = 2; Y = 1
Point 6: X = 2; Y = 4
Point 5: X = 2; Y = 6
Point 4: X = 3; Y = 8
Point 3: X = 4; Y = 1
Point 2: X = 4; Y = 2
```

I use this simple code:

```
myPointList.sort();
```

But I have an order that it's not the correct, because I have to remove some of this points, and if they have the order that I want, I erase the correct points but I remove the correct ones that I don't want to erase.

Can someone help me, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163922/sort-a-custom-class-listt

Comment: For future reference - downvotes are likely due to very broad "order is not correct" and lack of search effort like http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+sort+list+two+properties...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Linq:

```
Points.OrderBy(p => p.X).ThenBy(p => p.Y)
```

Comment: what is p? I only have my List<Point3d>... Should I have something like PointList.OrderBy(PointList => PointList[i].X).ThenBy(PointList => PointList[i].Y)?

Comment: p is a variable name inside lambda expression so it's name doesn't really matter as long as it is unique. You can refer to "p" as if you are looking at single Point3d, so you can access it's properties directly.

Comment: Don't forget to add using System.Linq;

Answer (score 1):

You may need to modify this slightly but the idea is to order by x then y

```
var sortedList = PointList.OrderBy(p => p.X)
                          .ThenBy(p => p.Y)
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: can you tell me what is p? sorry

Comment: @Imrik - The p just represents a point for the lambda expression, its a little bit like a temporary variable

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement a custom comparer and pass it as an argument cu the sort method.