# Merge Sort implementation for object lists c#

Tags: c#, implementation, mergesort

I'm making a program in c# and I got a list with objects which I want to sort with c#.
I can't get it working nor do I understand how it should be implemented.

I did some research for which algorithm I should use and came up with merge sort because it's always n(log n) and doesn't rely on a lucky chance with the pivot like quick sort to achieve it.

Anyways so far why I chose that and want it. :)

it's a list with weight
each weight contains a date and a bodyweight.
I want to get it sorted on the date and make the method return the sorted list.

Could someone help me to achieve this. You would help me out a lot :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1)Implement IComparable interface in your class.
   
2)Add your object to a List.
    
3)Call Sort() on the list object

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163922/sort-a-custom-class-listt

Comment: Yes, `IEnumerable<T>.Sort` will perform Quicksort but it is usually better than Mergesort. You need to have a really good reason to go with Mergesort, and above all that `IEnumerable<T>.Sort` is an excellent Quicksort implementation. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70402/why-is-quicksort-better-than-mergesort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use linq to sort collections, for example:

```
public IEnumerable<Weight> GetSortedWeights()
{
    var weights = new List<Weight>() { new Weight { Date = DateTime.Now, BodyWeight = 80 }, ... };

    return weights.OrderBy(x => x.Date);
}
```