# Merge sort days of week in order of weekday and not alphabetical

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I have an object array with a string property that represents the weekdays. I want to write a merge sort algorithm to sort my object array in order of weekdays.

I am capable of writing a merge sort algorithm but I am wondering how I could get it to sort it in order of weekdays and not by alphabet?
Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to write a sorting algorithm for a fixed input?

Comment: You need first to associate a numerical value that you can use to sort your entries. In C++ I would use a `std::map<std::string,int> dayOrder` and I would put dayOrder["Sunday"] = 0, dayOrder["Monday"] = 1, etc. I don't know though what's available in C#

Comment: Can you change your string property to [`DayOfWeek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @manpreetbhamba It's not a fixed input, I have 144 items in my object array and the day property ranges from monday-friday

Comment: Show us code you already have for merge sort algorithm.

Comment: MergeSort<T>(IList<T> list,IComparer<T> comparer)

Answer (score 3):

Use a collection for the objects that supports custom comparators, or just implement IComparable on your object [as demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3164012/2662901).  Then just use a static map of your property to an ordering or if you can map your string property to the DayOfWeek enum then use that built-in ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Don't write the sort algorithem, instead, write a simple Comparer that will implement IComparer, convert your array to a list , sort that list, and then convert back to an array if needed. a Possible comparer will be something like that:

```
Public WeekDayNameComparer<YourObject> : IComparer<yourObject> 
{
   private string[] WeekDays = {"sunday", "monday", ..."friday"}
   public int Compare(YourObject x, YourObject y) {
      return Array.indexOf(WeekDays, x.WeekDay).CompareTo(Array.indexOf(WeekDays, y.WeekDay));
   }
}
```