# Sort collection of users with a list of addresses (that contains coordinates) regarding to a location (lat and lng)

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by, distance, min

I have a list of users. Each user can have multiple addresses (that contains lat and lng). I need to sort the users depending on who has the nearest address to an specific point (lat and lng).

I'm trying stuff, but i'm quite bad with linq when it comes to some complex queries. What i'm trying here is to get the address of each user that has the minimum distance from the source and then sort the users by that value.

This is my code:

```
var sourceCoords = new GeoCoordinate(lat, lng);    // source point
users.OrderBy(c => c.userAdresses.Select(x => sourceCoords.GetDistanceTo(new GeoCoordinate(x.Lat, x.Lng))).Min());
```

Some help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to use Comparator for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163922/sort-a-custom-class-listt

Comment: What is the actual type of `users`? Is it really `List<User>`? Or are you using EF (if so, which?)?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your code?