# Listbox Auto sort numbers but exclude string

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a leaderboard in Windows forms using c# but I can't come up with a solution.

Here is my current code.

```cs
lstleaderboard.Items.Add(int.Parse(txtScore.Text));
ArrayList Sorting = new ArrayList();

foreach (var o in lstleaderboard.Items)
{
    Sorting.Add(o);
}

Sorting.Sort(new ReverseSort());

lstleaderboard.Items.Clear();

foreach (var o in Sorting)
{
    lstleaderboard.Items.Add(o);
}
```

And I tried altering the code like this:

```cs
lstleaderboard.Items.Add(int.Parse(txtScore.Text));
ArrayList Sorting = new ArrayList();

foreach (var o in lstleaderboard.Items)
{
    Sorting.Add(o);
}

Sorting.Sort(new ReverseSort());

lstleaderboard.Items.Clear();

foreach (var o in Sorting)
{
    lstleaderboard.Items.Add(o + txtName.Text );
}

if (lstleaderboard.Items.Count == 11)
{
    lstleaderboard.Items.RemoveAt(lstleaderboard.Items.Count - 1);
}
```

but this did not really work since it was then also sorting the names which messed up the scoreboard and it showed the wrong results, number one could be number three for example.

I am still learning so I apologize if my question is silly or my code is "weird"

Thanks

also here is my sorting class:

```
public class ReverseSort : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return Comparer.Default.Compare(y, x);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163922/sort-a-custom-class-listt

Comment: Slightly off-topic but it should be noted that ArrayList is a rather ancient datatype from the .NET Framework 1.0 era. [**Microsoft**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) writes this about it: "Important - We don't recommend that you use the `ArrayList` class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic `List<T>` class. The `ArrayList` class is designed to hold heterogeneous collections of objects. However, it does not always offer the best performance. Instead, we recommend .... ...."

Answer (score 0):

So `lstLeaderBoard` is just list of integers, so you can safely use integer comparison, the way you did it, it just uses some default comparer on object type, which is far away from integer.

So simple LINQ `OrderBy` would suffice:

```
lstLeaderBoard.Items.Add(int.Parse(txtScore.Text));
var sortedItems = lstLeaderBoard.Items.Cast<int>().OrderBy(x => x);
lstLeaderBoard.Items.Clear();
foreach (var item in sortedItems)
    lstLeaderBoard.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: If `lstLeaderBoard` is a ListBox, its ObjectCollection (`Items`) cannot be assigned. You could use `AddRange()`, storing the sorted items, e.g., `var sorted = [ListBox].Items.Cast<int>().OrderByDescending(x => x).Select(x => (object)x).ToArray(); [ListBox].Items.Clear(); [ListBox].Items.AddRange(sorted);` -- `Cast<int>()` because the OP is apparently boxing `int` values as objects

Comment: Anyway, it would be better to use a DataSource object that supports sorting

Comment: @Jimi right.. thanks and corrected my answer.

Comment: Nope. You cannot use `Select()` directly on a ObjectCollection, you have to use `Cast<>()` or `OfType<>()` beforehand (the latter won't work here) and also you cannot use `AddRange()` to insert an array of integers, you have to cast to object (it's an Object Collection). See my previous snippet.